# Test iPhone In App Purchase without uploading binary (i.e. without bundle ID)

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've created a new app but not uploaded a binary (not ready for review yet).
However, I want to test in-app purchases.

The documentation seems to state that a bundle ID is required to create an in-app purchase product. Is there any way to specify this bundle ID for creating the in-app purchase product on iTunes Connect without uploading the app binary in a way that won't cause problems when the actual binary is uploaded?

What if the eventually uploaded binary has a different bundleID than the use created for testing - does it effectively invalidate the in-app purchase product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be following the problem, so please clarify if I've got it wrong, but basically what you need for the bundle ID is the App ID you use to make your provisioning file for your project.  You might make it com.CoolGameCompany.SpaceWar.  I believe you just need to make sure your provisioning file has this app id and that you enter it as your bundle id.  Thereafter I don't think you should have problems with any binary created for distribution having a different ID.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the right direction. Thanks. To confirm, you're talking about the provisioning->App ID thing, right? Currently my App ID has a wildcard, so when I create/download the new AppID all I need to do is change stuff in XCode to use this new App ID, correct?

Comment: I believe you're on the right track.  Yes, I think it's the App ID you're talking about.  There are a couple places in various docs that mention not using a wildcard for your app id or it won't work with in-app purchases.  Try changing that to a non-wildcard and then using that to name your in-app products etc.